# Microsoft Dynamics Add-in Excel - Filtering multiple values

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, excel-addins

I use the Microsoft Dynamics Add-in to work with data in Excel tables.

When I update data from Dynamics, I have a filter on one column, so it only includes rows equal to the value "UDDAN" (see picture). Now I want to filter the same column so it also include rows with the value "PROJ".

How do I do this?

There seems to be no option saying "Include multiple". And I have tried to type "UDDAN|PROJ"- similar to how you do it in Dynamics web-browser version, but no luck.

[image]